# How to append a dataframe to an excel template?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have an `xlsx` template with some headers and other information, all I want is to fill that sheet with the dataframe without losing the contents of the template. Here's the code I'm using for that:

```
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('xls/template.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
 df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1',startrow=2,header=None)
 writer.save()
```

I read somewhere that, to use a template I must use openpyxl engine in the writer but even then the contents of the template are lost and the dataframe is written after 2 rows. The rows above had some headers before but now they are blank.

Comment: I had a similar issue and at the end I gave up.

Comment: See https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pandas.html

Comment: @CharlieClark that uses loop and with that method I have been doing this successfully but now there's a lot of data and appending that takes a lot of time. Since, `df.to_csv()` or `df.to_excel()` makes it faster I want to use that but the problem with this is, it doesn't let me append data to a template.

Comment: **All** methods that convert a dataframe to some kind of row use loops but the loops aren't slow. Converting the data from Python to XML is what takes the time.

Answer (score 4):

Just load the worksheet using openpyxl and write the dataframe into it.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

wb= openpyxl.load_workbook('H:/your/dir/template.xlsx')
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('xyz')
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 3):  #starts at 3 as you want to skip the first 2 rows
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
         ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)
```

Comment: This is what I was doing but what I want is to append whole dataframe without looping through each row i.e. `df.to_excel`

Comment: @FaizanAli to_excel is simply abstracting the loop

Answer (score 0):

An example can be:

```
test_df = pd.read_excel('xls/template.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
test_df = test_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('xls/template.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
test_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
```